# Torque.js is not working: L.TorqueLayer is not a constructor

Tags: carto, geocoding, carto-js, torque

I've been trying to create a carto map with a torque layer as indicated in the Torque.js documentation, but I keep getting the same error:

> Uncaught TypeError: L.TorqueLayer is not a constructor

```html
<script>
  var CARTOCSS = [
    'Map {',
    '-torque-time-attribute: "date";',
    '-torque-aggregation-function: "count(cartodb_id)";',
    '-torque-frame-count: 760;',
    '-torque-animation-duration: 15;',
    '-torque-resolution: 2',
    '}',
    '#layer {',
    '  marker-width: 3;',
    '  marker-fill-opacity: 0.8;',
    '  marker-fill: #FEE391; ',
    '  comp-op: "lighten";',
    '}'
  ].join('\n');

  var torqueLayer = new L.TorqueLayer({
    user: 'your_username',
    table: 'your_table_name',
    cartocss: CARTOCSS
  });
  torqueLayer.addTo(map);
  torqueLayer.play()
</script>
```

How can I make `L.TorqueLayer` work?

Comment: Could you share the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1):

remember to link Torque.js in your .html file.
for example(from github):

```
<script src="../dist/torque.full.uncompressed.js"  type="application/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

this should fix your problem.
if not,there is another solution:
you can use CartoDB.js library instead of directly using Torque.js:

```
 cartodb.createLayer(map, {
      type: "torque",
      order: 1,
      options: {
        table_name: "your table",
        user_name: "your user name",
        tile_style: 'your cartoCSS'
        }
    }).done(function(layer) {
      map.addLayer(layer);
    });
  }
```

html:

```
 <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

I am new to Torque too,also sorry for my rusty english,it's not my native language:)